# Solr Cloud Index Sizes

Tags: solr, solrcloud

what is the Solr Cloud equivalent to ElasticSearch's _cat queries to determine the index sizes?

In ElasticSearch I can simply call

```
http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices/?v&s=index
```

or

```
http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards/?v
```

to see how much space (in bytes) a index or a shard uses. The only way I found in Solr cloud so far is to add up file sizes on every node. Is there any way to ask Solr cloud directly for this information?